# Powerpoint - can I do this?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have been asked to create a powerpoint presentation that is a then and now.  So, what I want to do is to have the then photo on half the slide and then have the now photo appear beside it.  Can I do this?  If so, how?  Thanks!

Comment: You just crop the image(s) so they take only 50% of the slide.  Have you tried doing this?  You can make something "appear" using a effect transition.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm just not sure how to use the effect on half a screen.  I'm sure that this is really basic, I've just never done it before.

Comment: Its one of those things we cannot do for you.

Comment: [PowerPoint Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eT6IH-CSSPE)

Answer (score 3):

-First, insert both images and line them up where you want them to be when they're both on the screen.
-Then click on the picture that is meant to appear (the "after" picture), and click "Animations" at the top.
-Choose the "Appear" option or whichever other animation you prefer.
 When you're in the slide show, the "after" picture will appear when you click the mouse button.